# Do amazon ec2 linux instances run on VMWare?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created an Amazon EC2 instance (redhat 6) to run a 3d application (linux only app using openInventor) on the cloud. I installed VirtualGL, vnc and installed my application. I ran it in a vnc session using vglrun and everything went well except rendering objects that used shading language didn't work the way they were supposed to. 
I had the same problem when I tried running my application through VMWare on a windows box. 
So I was wondering if Amazon servers are all windows based and linux EC2 instances are created through VMWare or some other virtual mechanism? Or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS's EC2 service runs mostly on Linux servers, nearly a half-million of them according to the article below. They are running a modified version of the Xen hypervisor.

http://www.zdnet.com/blog/open-source/amazon-ec2-cloud-is-made-up-of-almost-half-a-million-linux-servers/10620